# Flutter Toggle Switch Text Overflow

Tags: android, flutter, toggleswitch

Hi I'm trying to implement Toggle Switch in MCQ Quiz App.
But the text **overflow is ellipsis**. I have tried **customTextStyles** but no change in UI.
I just want the overflow to be visible not ellipsis.
Can Someone help me with this... ???

```
ToggleSwitch(
          initialLabelIndex: 0,
          animate: true,
          isVertical: true,
          minWidth:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          animationDuration: 400,
          activeBgColor: [Colors.green],
          inactiveBgColor: hexToColor("#928FFF"),
          minHeight: 70,
          totalSwitches: 4,
          borderWidth: 30,
          cornerRadius: 20,
          customTextStyles: const [
            TextStyle(
                overflow: TextOverflow.visible, fontSize: 17, inherit: false)
          ],
          labels: [
            "A.) ${answers[0]}",
            "B.) ${answers[1]}",
            "C.) ${answers[2]}",
            "D.) ${answers[3]}"
          ],
          onToggle: (index) {
            print('switched to: ${index}');
          },
        ),
```

[image: This is My UI..]

Comment: you can't do this as of now. checkout this link for more details - https://github.com/PramodJoshi/toggle_switch/issues/22

Comment: for above UI you can use listviewBuilder with handle selection option index easily without any package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't show multiple lines in `Toggle switch` widget, check out this [link](https://github.com/PramodJoshi/toggle_switch/issues/22) for more details.

> You can simply handle this using `listView widget` and simple
> `selection logic` for your quiz `multiline questions`. check example
> for one question you can handle for all quiz questions.

```
final answers = [
    "work done in both is same but the rate of",
    "work done in rolling a stone is less than in lorem ipsum ...",
    "work done in rolling is more than in lifting",
    "work done in lifting the stone is equal to lorem ipsum lorem ipsum"
  ];

int selectedIndex = -1; // By default no any answer selected.

ClipRRect(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
child: ListView.builder(
    physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: 4,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          color:
              selectedIndex == index ? Colors.green : Colors.purple,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("${String.fromCharCode((65 + index))})."), // OPTIONS CHAR
                const SizedBox(width: 8),
                Expanded(child: Text(" ${answers[index]}"))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }),
)
```

output:
[image]